# php gzip match unix gzip

Tags: php, unix, gzip

I am trying to use php to create a file and zip it. How can i match the same compression levels/headers/and so on as gzip that is run in unix?

using php

```
ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner owner 486 Jul 21 17:05 file.xml.gz
```

using gzip on unix command line:

```
  ls -l
 total 8
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 owner owner 479 Jul 21 17:05 file.xml.gz
```

in php

```
  $zip = gzencode($xml,2);
```

i have tried 0 through 9 as the compression level here, i have also tried

```
 $zip = gzencode($xml,x,FORCE_DEFLATE)
```

again where x is 0-9

my problem is this:

I have a 3rd party vendor that takes the gzipped file, unzips it and does fun things with it.  The problem i am running into is when i use php i get an error "cannot parse file.xm.gz",  when i use gzip on cli it works fine.  I have no vision into what the 3rd party is doing or why its failing.  Could it be something like carriage returns or spaces or something in the xml? I know its a tough question to answer. heres a snippet of my php xml.

```
   $xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
               <localRoutes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        ';
     $xml.='<route>
             <user type="string">' . $mac . '</user>
             ';
     $xml.='<next type="regex">!^(.*$)!sip:@' . $ip . "</next>
             </route>
             ";
      $xml .= '</localRoutes>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The compressed data is identical. What's missing is a field in the header indicating the original name of the file (e.g, probably `file.xml` here). This field is generated by the `gzip` utility, but the `gzencode()` PHP function doesn't have an original filename to work with, so it doesn't write this field.

I'm not aware of any way to make PHP generate this field with the zlib extension. Its absence is very unlikely to cause any problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't.
2. You don't need to.

First, gzip and zlib (which is what php is using) have different compression algorithms, and so for large enough data, they will never produce the same compressed data, even at the same compression level.

Second, as noted by @duskwuff, you will not be able to replicate the same gzip header, unless you pull off the gzip header that php made and write your own.  The modification dates in the headers will be different.  The way you're doing it, one will have a file name and one will not.  Though you can invoke gzip with `-n` to not store the file name.

Third, there is no reason to try to make the results identical.  All that matters is that both decompress to the same thing.  Which they will.

Comment: First: Hm? `gzencode()` generates RFC1952 compliant output, same as gzip. Same compression algorithm and everything.

Comment: Compliant, yes.  Identical, no.  There are many possible compliant compressions of the same data.